# Which of the given sorting algorithms will be fastest when run on an array that happens to already be in order?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Question:

Which sorting algorithm will be fastest when run on an array that happens to already be in order?

(A) It is not possible to know which will be fastest.

(B) selection sort

(C) insertion sort

(D) binary sort

(E) All of these algorithms will run at the same speed.

I have been doing some research for a homework assignment and have been getting conflicting answers. Some places say it is insertion, while some say both are equal and yet others say it can't be determined. Very confused right now, would appreciate some help.

Comment: What kind of help? The answer?

Comment: @DaveNewton : The last time that I looked this up, stackoverflow was still a **Question and Answer** site. There are millions of "homework solutions" here, regardless of whether they are declared (or recoginzable) as such. If I wanted to know this answer, I would want (and expect!) to find it here.

Comment: This should be trivial to figure out if you just trace what each algorithm will do for a sorted array.

Answer (score 1):

C Insertion sort

Is normally always the fastest and easiest to implement when an array is already nearly or completely sorted. As we have less operations.

Selection sort will still do pair wise comparison and binary sort will also be slightly slower.

Comment: Although not listed as an option, natural bottom up merge sort would also be O(n), making one pass to determine that there is a single sorted run and nothing to merge.

Comment: For this answer to be useful, it should explain *why* insertion sort will be faster and why the others aren't.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that insertion sort because:

**Insertion sort** is a simple sorting algorithm, it builds the final sorted array one item at a time. It is much less efficient on large lists than other sort algorithms.

Advantages of Insertion Sort:

1) It is very simple.

2) It is very efficient for small data sets.

3) It is stable; i.e., it does not change the relative order of elements with equal keys.
4) In-place; i.e., only requires a constant amount O(1) of additional memory space.

Insertion sort iterates through the list by consuming one input element at each repetition, and growing a sorted output list. On a repetition, insertion sort removes one element from the input data, finds the location it belongs within the sorted list, and inserts it there. It repeats until no input elements remain.

I read this at- http://www.java2novice.com/java-sorting-algorithms/insertion-sort/